# Multiple Buttons in FloatingActionButton library

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

Hi I an trying to implement [FloatingActionButton][1] Library by makovkastar. (As it is backward compatible. It works fine with single FAB, but when 2 Buttons are added, the "List" seems to get attached to only one buttons.

**fragment_listview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"/>

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/accent"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/accent_pressed"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/ripple"/>

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/accent"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/accent_pressed"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/ripple"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity ListViewFragment Class**

```
public static class ListViewFragment extends Fragment {

        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, container, false);

            ListView list = (ListView) root.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            ListViewAdapter listAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(),
                    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries));
            list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) root.findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.attachToListView(list);

            FloatingActionButton fab2 = (FloatingActionButton) root.findViewById(R.id.fab2);
            fab2.attachToListView(list);



            return root;
        }
```

This is same code sample provided in [that library](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton):

When the list is scrolled, only one button (**fab2** in this case) becomes invisible when scrolled down. I want both the buttons to react to scroll.

Any idea to anyone how this can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this yourself, by making your fragment implement [com.melnykov.fab.ScrollDirectionListener](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/melnykov/fab/ScrollDirectionListener.java) (also from the same package as the fab).

```
public static class ListViewFragment extends Fragment implements
    com.melnykov.fab.ScrollDirectionListener {

    private FloatingActionButton fab, fab2;

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, container, false);

        ListView list = (ListView) root.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        ListViewAdapter listAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(),
                    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries));
        list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) root.findViewById(R.id.fab);
            // this method expects a ScrollDirectionListener as second arg
            // so use this for that parameter
            fab.attachToListView(list, this);

        fab2 = (FloatingActionButton) root.findViewById(R.id.fab2);
            fab2.attachToListView(list, this);

            return root;
        }

    @Override
    public void onScrollDown() {
        if (fab.isVisible() || fab2.isVisible()) {
            fab.hide();
            fab2.hide();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollUp() {
        if (!fab.isVisible() || !fab2.isVisible()) {
            fab.show();
            fab2.show();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure this should work, but in the case it doesn't you should [open an issue](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton/issues) to propose this possible bug to the developer.

**Note**

Android now has it's own implementation of the [FloatingActionButton](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog) (and much more) in the [design library](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html). Include it in your project with this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Here is an [excellent guide](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Floating-Action-Buttons) for using the new FAB with lists; it even includes use of the new [CoordinatorLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) which should replace need for scroll listeners and such

Comment: Gosh was that easy! Thanks a ton! And I know about FloatingActionButton in design library, but I want my app to be backward compatible :)